# Connection to SharePoint list on SP 2010/13 STANDARD Edition

Tags: excel

My organisation will downgrade from SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition to SharePoint 2013 **Standard** edition. I am not part of the decision making, but I heard the decision relates to cost or licensing.

Under Enterprise Edition, I have Excel workbooks linked to SharePoint lists. Will those still work?

Comment: you want downgrade in SP2010 and move to 2013?

Comment: We are actually using Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Edition. Shortly we should move to Sharepoint 2013 Standard Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should still work to the best of my knowledge. I believe connecting workbooks to Excel is available in all SKUs of the product, Foundation, Standard, and Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

downgrading from enterprise to standard is not easy path.

1. you have to clean the farm first, uninstalling the EE features.
2. Rebuild the farm with Standard Key.

http://www.concurrency.com/blog/sharepoint-enterprise-standard-edition-downgrade/
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e1f0030-54ad-48dd-8813-18a0c09dd9db/downgrading-sp-2013-enterprise-to-2013-standard?forum=sharepointadmin
If you excel work book is using the Excel service Application's funcationality then it will not work. But you can test it once you uninstall the EE features.

Comment: I am quite new to SharePoint, and I might not be involved in the server administration aspect of the migration. I will be pleased to transmit your information to our admins. All my connections do is retrieve SP list. A local pivot-table (not PowerPivot) is then updated. I'm trying to find a standard trial edition to make tests. Thanks

Comment: i dont think you will get the free trail of standard version unless you have the MSDN subscription. More over, you will have too many issues with backup and recovery.

Comment: Effectively, it does not seem to be available. Thanks for the information.